# Android. dp's don't do their job

Tags: android, dpi

1. New -> Android project for testing the problem
2. Code for **Test.java**:

   package test.density.yeah;

   ```
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.os.Bundle;

   public class TestActivity extends Activity {
       /** Called when the activity is first created. */
       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.main);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Code for **main.xml**:

   ```
   <ImageButton
   android:background="@null"
   android:src="@drawable/icon"
   android:layout_width="200dp"
   android:layout_height="200dp">
   </ImageButton>
   ```
4. Started emulator with settings:

Resolution - **480x800**

Avstracted LCD Density - **190**

**RESULT**:

http://cs5961.userapi.com/u68152416/-3/y_ef134df2.jpg

After that I've started emulator with such settings:

Resolution - **480x800**

Avstracted LCD Density - **240**

**RESULT**:

http://cs5961.userapi.com/u68152416/-3/y_8b99507b.jpg

Emulator settings for the first test mathes my HTC HD2 characteristics and second is the same as the HTC Sensation XL is. When running this test app on them
it is the same problem. **HD2 (480x800, 190dpi) - small image**, **Sensation (480x800, 240dpi) - huge image**.

So why "**density independent pixels**" do not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works fine, but there's a twist you need to know about.

You're using the src attribute on the View. If you do that, the View will be sized according to the bitmap size, and you'd normally have different versions for the various densities, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi etc. It will ignore layout_height and layout_width.

If you want your View to ignore the bitmap size and use the layout_width and layout_height values to force the size, you need to use the background attribute, not src.

```
<ImageButton
    android:background="@drawable/icon"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp">
</ImageButton>
```

Comment: Oh no. I have mistaken. I started both tests at 190 density. And really it doesn't work. If use 480x800 and 190dpi - normal image, if 480x800 and 240dpi - large. Everything is as it was before. No changings... Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: It does work, I use these features on an almost daily basis. I suggest you add an "Update" section to your question and provide more details for people to help.

Comment: That's cool ... but what if I actually need a background too, and want my images to scale?

Answer (score 1):

May be the image scaling make your result gone wrong, you can read more about image scaling here:

`http://thebigbyte.blogspot.com/2009/12/android-how-to-scale-image-in-imageview.html`

You can test the result by change the ImageButton xml to

```
<ImageButton
android:background="#ffffff"
android:layout_width="200dp"
android:layout_height="200dp">
</ImageButton>
```